# Python/Pandas - split text into columns by delimiter ; and create a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have a long text where I have inserted a delimiter ";" exactly where I would like to split the text into different columns.
So far, whenever I try to split the text into 'ID' and 'ADText' I only get the first line. However there should be 1439 lines/rows in two columns.

My text looks like this:
1234; text in written from with multiple sentences going over multiple lines until at some point the next ID is written dwon 2345; then the new Ad-Text begins until the next ID 3456; and so on

I want to use the ; to split my text into two Columns, one with ID and one with the AD Text.

```
#read the text file into python: 
jobads= pd.read_csv("jobads.txt", header=None)
print(jobadsads)

#create dataframe 
df=pd.DataFrame(jobads, index=None, columns=None)
type(df)
print(df)
#name column to target it for split 
df = df.rename(columns={0:"Job"})
print(df)

#split it into two columns. Problem: I only get the first row.
print(pd.DataFrame(dr.Job.str.split(';',1).tolist(),
                   columns=['ID','AD']))
```

Unfortunately that only works for the first entry and then it stops. The output looks like this:

```
               ID                                                 AD
0            1234                                   text in written from with ...
```

Where am I going wrong? I would appreciate any advise =)
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use the "sep" attribute of "pd.read_csv" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sample text:

```
FullName;ISO3;ISO1;molecular_weight
Alanine;Ala;A;89.09
Arginine;Arg;R;174.20
Asparagine;Asn;N;132.12
Aspartic_Acid;Asp;D;133.10
Cysteine;Cys;C;121.16
```

Create columns based on ";" separator:

```
import pandas as pd
f = "aminoacids"
df = pd.read_csv(f,sep=";")
```

[image]

EDIT: Considering the comment I assume the text looks more something like this:

```
t = """1234; text in written from with multiple sentences going over multiple lines until at some point the next ID is written dwon 2345; then the new Ad-Text begins until the next ID 3456; and so on1234; text in written from with multiple """
```

In this case regex like this will split your string into ids and text which you can then use to generate a pandas dataframe.

```
import re
r = re.compile("([0-9]+);")
re.split(r,t)
```

Output:

```
['',
 '1234',
 ' text in written from with multiple sentences going over multiple lines until at some point the next ID is written dwon ',
 '2345',
 ' then the new Ad-Text begins until the next ID ',
 '3456',
 ' and so on',
 '1234',
 ' text in written from with multiple ']
```

EDIT 2:
This is a response to questioners additional question in the comments:
*How to convert this string to a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: IDs and Texts*

```
import pandas as pd
# a is the output list from the previous part of this answer
# Create list of texts. ::2 takes every other item from a list, starting with the FIRST one.
texts = a[::2][1:] 
print(texts)
# Create list of ID's. ::1 takes every other item from a list, starting with the SECOND one
ids = a[1::2]
print(ids)
df = pd.DataFrame({"IDs":ids,"Texts":texts})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried this and it gives me 0 rows and 19090 columns since my text is not sorted like your example. I have the ID not written nicely in front of each line but free-flowing in the text.

Comment: Ah I see so you don't even have new lines? It is just a long single line string?

Comment: Yes it is one single line string sadly

Comment: @Nina Have you checked the edit of my answer? Would it help or are there any other scenarios that it doesen‘t capture?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer! It helps a lot and it worked! Awesome really, thanks!

Comment: @Nina No problem, glad to help. Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Dear Amueba, how would you put it into a pandas dataframe? I would like to have one column with ID and one Column with the AD Text. However, after the split when I put it on csv it is all in one column written underneath each other. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nina I have supplemented my answer with additional edit. I think that should solve it for you. Also a tip here on StackOwerflow you can tag a person you are reffering to with "@" before their name

Comment: thank you so much, you are my hero! :D I will work on my reputation and give you a huge upvote when I reached 15 :D before it doesn't count, I am sorry =)